# error link image button to fragment error: no suitable constructor found for

Tags: android, android-studio, constructor, fragment, imagebutton

Hey guys so i'm trying to get my imagebutton to work within my fragment.  What do I need to change? error: no suitable constructor found

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    Button myproductButton;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

        myproductButton = myproductButton.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        myproductButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeFragment.this, myProducts.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get inflate your layout first then find Your Button

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);// inflate layout first

    myproductButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);// here is how to get button
    myproductButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), myProducts.class); // you should pass activity as context
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 return view;

}
```

Comment: The problem is cannot resolve constructor `Intent intent = new Intent(HomeFragment.this, myProducts.class);`

Comment: edited the answer, but you should inflate your layout first as stated